# Functional Analysis for Quantum Mechnanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, resource-recommendations, mathematics

I have completed three sequences of courses in QM, and I'm very much eager to to do the functional analysis of QM on my own in my spare time.

Can someone suggest some books? I like books with mathematical rigor, and I'm taking this step to understand the mathematical foundations of Hilbert Spaces used in QM.

Also, please do let me know the pre-requisites to study the book(s) you're mentioning.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41020/discussion-on-question-by-junaid-aftab-functional-analysis-for-quantum-mechnanic).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/598/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22409/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

[This functional analysis textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824785983) is quite good, it even has a chapter dedicated on some of the mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics without using this name. This book is quite compact though, the [classic text by Walter Rudin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070542368) is more detailed. Prerequisites are topology and measure theory.